# How to add attachment_ids in odoo message

Tags: react-native, expo, odoo-10

im trying to add attachment in a odoo message programmly using react-native-odoo-promise-based.

first i've create ir.attachment and it show success value {success: true, data: 1096}.

then i try to add this id (1096) to attachment_ids in mail.message

```
    const data = {
        message_type: "comment",
        add_sign: false,
        reply_to: "Mitchell Admin <test@test.com>",
        attachment_ids: [1096],
        body: '<p>Coba WhiteCake</p>',
        create_date: "2019-05-20 08:15:47",
        display_name: "PO00013 (44)",
        record_name: "PO00013 (44)",
        author_id: 3,
        add_sign: false,

    }
    odoo.create('mail.message', data)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.log(e);
            console.log('eror')
        });
});
```

it show success result too,

```
    {success: true, data: 1178}
```

then i've read mail.messsage id 1178

```
add_sign: false
attachment_ids: []
```

but attachment_ids still has an empty array.

i've already try this :

attachment_id: ['1096']

attachment_id: [(0,'1096')]

attachment_id: [(0,1096)],

attachment_id: [(1096)],

attachment_id: 1096,

attachment_id: [1096],

attachment_ids: [1096],

attachment_ids: [(1096)],

attachment_ids: [('1096')],

attachment_ids: [(0,'1096')],

attachment_ids: [(0,1096)],

attachment_ids: [('0','1096')],

attachment_ids: [(0,1096)],

attachment_ids: '[1096]',

but attachment_ids still has an empty array.